# What's the real use of useContext flutter hook when it can't be called outside the build method?

Tags: flutter, hook, flutter-hooks

I recently started working with **flutter_hooks** but then I wondered what is the benefit of having a hook that returns the build context in the build method that is already provides the build context..!!

Have anyone a good explanation for this?

Comment: Maybe in a callback... might not have context handy there, but the hooks have to remember it.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz how?

Comment: Without `useContext`, you have to pass context to function/method whenever necessary.

Comment: You can use ```useContext()``` in a method outside the ```build()``` method of your HookWidget instead of passing context in the method inputs.

Comment: @Taleb doesn't work for me.